# Can't save string into SQLite database (SQLITE_DONE doesn't return true)

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to store strings in a SQLite database for an iOS 6 iPhone Application. It's fairly simple: a joke is displayed in a textview when clicking a button. When clicking a second button, I want to save that textview into the SQLite database (saveJoke). However, SQLITE_DONE is never returned, indicating this is not working. So, looking at my alerts, I always get "Fail" when saveJoke is executed below.

Any idea why this is not working? I have a feeling I might be missing something basic in the creation of and inserting into the SQLite database. Very thankful for help!

My code:

JokeFirstViewController.m:

```
#import "JokeFirstViewController.h"

@interface JokeFirstViewController ()

@end

@implementation JokeFirstViewController

@synthesize joke = _joke;

- (void)viewDidLoad
    {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *docsDir;
    NSArray *dirPaths;

    dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
                                               NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    docsDir = dirPaths[0];

    // Build the path to the database file
    _databasePath = [[NSString alloc]
                 initWithString: [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:
                                  @"contacts.db"]];

    NSFileManager *filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    if ([filemgr fileExistsAtPath: _databasePath ] == NO)
    {
    const char *dbpath = [_databasePath UTF8String];

    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &_contactDB) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        char *errMsg;
        const char *sql_stmt =
        "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CONTACTS (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, JOKESAVED TEXT)"; //look into

        sqlite3_close(_contactDB);

    }
  }
}

- (IBAction)saveJoke:(id)sender {

    /* get current joke displayed */
    self.joke = self.text.text;
    NSString *currentJoke = self.joke;
    NSString *jokeSaved = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:currentJoke];

    sqlite3_stmt    *statement;
    const char *dbpath = [_databasePath UTF8String];

    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &_contactDB) == SQLITE_OK)
    {

        NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                               @"INSERT INTO CONTACTS (jokesaved) VALUES (?)",
                               jokeSaved];

        const char *insert_stmt = [insertSQL UTF8String];
        sqlite3_prepare_v2(_contactDB, insert_stmt,
                           -1, &statement, NULL);
        if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
        {
            void AlertWithMessage(NSString *message);
            {
                UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Database" message:@"Success" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                [alert show];
            }
        } else {
            void AlertWithMessage(NSString *message);
            {
                UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Database" message:@"Fail" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                [alert show];
            }

        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        sqlite3_close(_contactDB);
    }

    }

}
```

JokeFirstViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MessageUI/MFMessageComposeViewController.h>
#import <sqlite3.h>

@interface JokeFirstViewController : UIViewController <MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate>


- (IBAction)saveJoke:(id)sender;

- (IBAction)shareJoke:(id)sender;

- (IBAction)generateJoke:(id)sender;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *text;

@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *joke;

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *databasePath;

@property (nonatomic) sqlite3 *contactDB;

@end
```

Comment: has you realized that you are not running the create table sentence?

Comment: You should check the result of `sqlite3_prepare_v2` and make sure that's `SQLITE_OK`. And if not, look at `sqlite3_errmsg()` to get a nice explanation of why it failed.

Comment: But, tkanzanic is right, you really should `sqlite3_exec` that create table SQL if you want it to create the table. And you really should always check the result codes for all `sqlite3` function calls, and if they fail, do the `NSLog(@"%s: %s", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(contactDB));`

Comment: Thank you. Strange, this guide I've followed has left out sqlite3_exec (only present in an if statement). Is it inaccurate? http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Example_SQLite_based_iOS_6_iPhone_Application

Comment: Could you please show me how to run the create table sentence in the above code to get it working?

Answer (score 1):

You have also to check the INSERT query, your stringFormat is wrong:

Change:

```
NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                               @"INSERT INTO CONTACTS (jokesaved) VALUES (?)", jokeSaved];
```

to:

```
NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                               @"INSERT INTO CONTACTS (jokesaved) VALUES ('%@')", jokeSaved];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (insert_statement == nil)
{  
    const char * sql = "INSERT INTO CONTACTS (jokesaved) VALUES (?)";
    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &insert_statement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) 
    {
       NSAssert1(0, @"Error: Failed to prepare SQL statement: %s.",sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    }
}
@try 
{
   sqlite3_bind_text (insert_statement, 1, [jokesSaved UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT );
}
@catch (NSException *exception)
{
  ;
}
int val = sqlite3_step(insert_statement);
if ( val != SQLITE_DONE) 
{
   NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to prepare SQL property insert statement: %s.", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
} 
else 
{

}
```

Comment: Do you have a full working example? Having some trouble putting this in the context of my code above.

Comment: Why are you wrapping the call to `sqlite3_bind_text` in a `try/catch` block? There is no need for that.